# Interfacing microcontroller with 1.8V logic

Tags: cortex-m3, level-translation

I am in the process of selecting a microcontroller to interface (~30 signal lines) to an FPGA that operates at 1.8V voltage levels.

I have found NXP's Cortex M0's to operate down to 1.8V which is great, but the bulk of Cortex M3 chips out there have a minimum operating voltage of 2V.

Should I restrict myself to the M0's? Or should I just use level translators? Are there Cortex M3 implementations that have an I/O voltage of 1.8v?

Note that I do have other voltage levels available on the board, but i just need the micro's I/O voltage to be compatible with 1.8V logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NXP has 74 different Cortex-M0 controllers, so if the M0's performance is good enough (they run at 50 MHz maximum), then you'll probably find a type which has the right features for your application.

If you want more options or need a higher performance you could go for the Cortex-M3 combined with a [GTL2000](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/GTL2000.pdf).

[image]

The GTL2000 offers you 22 fast channels which you can use unidirectional or bidirectional, and as you can see in the diagram you can interface with several voltage levels with a single device. The GTL2000 can work with levels between 1 V and 5 V on either side. This is a cost-effective solution if you have many lines between the controller and FPGA, but there are also versions with less transceivers if you can do with less. The [GTL2010](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/GTL2010.pdf) is a 10-channel version.

Answer (score 0):

it depends, read the microcontroller manual and find out what's the voltage level that specified in the manual. Not only the voltage level, for a example TTL means 
lots of electrical specifications than just 5V.

see : http://infosys.co.kr/e002/e002-s01.html

so guessing that you talking about a TTL microcontroller interface, you need to have 
at least 2.0 to represent logic level 1.

So the answer is YES. You need a level converter.

Comment: why downvote? curious.